# can't add UIView from a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, load

I have some issue showing a view from a view controller. Basically, I have a UIViewController class, I programmatically created the view by overloading loadView method. Here is the code that I have:

```
UIView* view = controller.view;  
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;  
if(!window)  
{  
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];  
}  
[window addSubview:view];
```

The view is not visible.

However, if I created a simple view based app by calling

```
[self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
```

Everything works well.

I am new to the iOS View Programming. Anything I did was wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Steve. Incidentally, if you use the code formatter (the {} icon in the editor) on your code it'll automatically be formatted correctly. I've also updated you question with the "ios" and "iphone" tags.

Answer (score 0):

Steve,

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but a typical iphone app will have a base UIViewController subclass, say a nav controller or tab controller and that controller's view is added as a subview of the UIWindow view in the appDelegate class.

You then instantiate further UIViewControllers or subclasses thereof and those views get added as subviews of the current view and so on.

Have you checked out the basic templates in XCode? These should show you how the appDelegate and the like works. You generally don't need to mess with UIWindow in other classes, in my experience.

Comment: Thanks. You mean I can't add a UIView to UIWindow? I looked at FB Connect, it add a UIView to UIWindow and it worked. But when I tried to add the view from UIViewController to the view, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Steve No, I'm not saying you can't add a UIView to a UIWindow, just I don't know why you are trying to do something this way, based on the snippet of code you provided. If you are new to iOS dev, maybe you want to learn from something simpler than FB Connect..